# Can we use Annotations completely for the whole project?

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations, hibernate-annotations, spring-annotations

I just wanna ask one thing regarding Annotations. I searched in google a lot and I read from many sites, BUT still iam not convinced. So, thats why i wanna ask myself.

Here are the queries:

1. I knew what annotations are, BUT i don't understand whether to use them in real projects or not. Some people say that it's very complex to understand, confusing and maintain them. Some people say they save a lot of time.
2. I have one spring project which i am gonna start with. Would you really suggest me to use Annotations for the whole project? (I knew how to use them)
3. When should we use them exactly and when shouldn't?

Personally, even I hate annotations as I feel they're not much maintainable, instead I love using xml files (of course I do not dump all tags in a single xml file, I maintain each xml for each layer (say `dispatcher-dao.xml` for dao layer, `dispatcher-view.xml` for presentation lauer, etc.)

So, could you please clear me these queries?

Awaiting your responses!

Comment: At the end, it is a matter of taste. Wether XML nor annotations are 'better'

Comment: Spring beans can yield complicated things too. In pure Java EE annotations can be less error prone, and speed things up, as you do not need to switch as often between sources, have the responsibility at one spot. For a *model* however, XML gives a nice overview.

Comment: @JoopEggen : Shall I go with only using Annotations? (instead of xml configuration files) for my whole project?

Comment: please, i need some more responses...

Comment: Spring is configurable post-build, so for projects that get installed at customer sites you at least want some of the key configurable options in XML and not annotations.

Comment: @Irwin as you have XML experience, putting all or a great part on annotations cannot be that harmful (you are capable of doing a rollback fast enough). So try it. Maybe immediately make a *reporting tool*, that gives a structured overview of your annotations (annotation processor).

Comment: @JoopEggen :  If you do not mind, can you show me with any example? Iam just thinking to have a clear idea when shouldnt we go with Annotations

Comment: Am not current in Spring but in JEE all the beans, servlets and servlet filters can be annotated - but only put servlet filters in a library jar as abstract base class without annotation (or define an exclude in annotation processing). There one looses not much info.